# Unable to connect to Hbase when Kerberos Enabled

Tags: hadoop, hbase, kerberos

I enabled Kerberos to secure hadoop and generated key tab for principal test@EXAMPLE.COM and provided test user RX (read execute) permission using hbase shell -grant command when i do 
    kinit -k -t test.keytab test@EXAMPLE.COM

everything works fine .I am trying to do the same thing like reading table via Java code/Java Client using below code

```
     System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", "EXAMPLE.COM");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", "D-9539.mydomain.com");
        //System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");

    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    config.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
    config.set("hbase.security.authentication", "kerberos");
    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(config);
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "D-9539.mydomain.com");
    config.setInt("zookeeper.recovery.retry",1);
    config.set("zookeeper.znode.parent","/hbase-secure");
    config.set("hbase.client.retries.number", Integer.toString(2));
    config.set("zookeeper.session.timeout", Integer.toString(60000));
      UserGroupInformation userGroupInformation = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI("mohanv@EXAMPLE.COM", "D:\\mohanv.keytab" );
      //UserGroupInformation userGroupInformation = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI("hbase-D9539@EXAMPLE.COM", "/Users/guest/Work/workspace/hbase.headless.keytab" );
    UserGroupInformation.setLoginUser(userGroupInformation);
    Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
    TableName tablename=TableName.valueOf("tweetTest2");
    Table table = conn.getTable(tablename);
    Get get=new Get(Bytes.toBytes("row1")) ;
    get.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("twt"));

    System.out.println(Bytes.toString(table.get(get).getRow()));
```

But getting

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException:
```

and then

```
clientClosingConnectionException
```

Comment: After enabling debug logs i am getting below Warning
2016-05-10 11:29:18 WARN  AbstractRpcClient:695 - Couldn't setup connection for mohanv@EXAMPLE.COM to null

Comment: More debug options: https://github.com/steveloughran/kerberos_and_hadoop/blob/master/sections/secrets.md

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll also need to set up the service principals in your HBase configuration. The following properties must be present, with the service principals for your HBase master and region server configured:

`hbase.master.kerberos.principal
hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal`

Another alternative is to add hbase-site.xml to the classpath, which should have these properties set.

Answer (score 0):

you need below properties to be set in your configuration.
exat Values for regional server and master server can be obtained from 
conf/hbase-site.xml. Check for relevant properties

```
//what principal the master/region. servers use.
    config.set("hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal", "hbase/_HOST@FIELD.HORTONWORKS.COM"); 
    config.set("hbase.regionserver.keytab.file", "src/hbase.service.keytab"); 

    // this is needed even if you connect over rpc/zookeeper
    config.set("hbase.master.kerberos.principal", "hbase/_HOST@FIELD.HORTONWORKS.COM"); 
    config.set("hbase.master.keytab.file", "src/hbase.service.keytab");
```

refer [here](https://github.com/kartik-dev/HBase-Example/blob/master/src/com/demo/hbase/HBaseClient.java)